# JSON or Mutli Dimensional Array (Map<String, Object>) To URL Parameters

Tags: rest-api, data-types

What's the simplest way to take an object of variable structure and convert it into a URL?

**I'm looking for the Apex equivalent of jQuery.param(array) in JavaScript or http_build_query() in PHP.**

Here's an example query object:

```
Map<String, Object> productQueryParams = new Map<String, Object>{
        'q'=>new Map<String,Object>{
                'category'=>'shoes',
                'colors'=> new List<String>{'blue','purple'}
         };
}
```

And the function I'm looking for would convert this to:

```
?q[category]=shoes&q[colors][]=blue&q[colors][]=purple
```

I know how to do this assuming the Map is single level or it's a known structure, but I'd like to do it with parameters of variable structure with multiple levels if possible.

Comment: What's your specific use case? Are you trying to send it between pages, or between servers/services?

Comment: between servers